# How can I enumerate the root of C: and all subfolders

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a bit confused here.  I wrote the following script to add files of a certain extension type to a List and it DOES work, just not for the root of C:  Here's the code first...

```
        // Create an empty list
        List<string> scanFiles = new List<string>();

        // Split possible extention list into array
        string[] scanExtensions = @"exe,com".Split(',');

        try
        {
            foreach (string extension in scanExtensions)
            {
                // Add collection for this filetype to the list of files
                scanFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*." + extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }

        // Display results
        foreach(string sf in scanFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sf);
        }
```

So if I run the above code, I get an error - but not the error I expect.  It displays the following...

**ERROR: Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\' is denied.**

I'd understand this if I hadn't specified 'C:\' as the directory path!  If I change this to any valid directory (such as C:\Program Files), the code works fine.  Can anyone explain this?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: And if you change it to C:\Documents and Settings\ ?

Comment: Have you made sure that you have the permissions on c:. If its a web app make sure that the app pool user has read permissions on that directiry

Comment: Oh my god - apologies all.  I was having a proper dumb moment. For some reason my brain blocked the possibility that the error was occurring AFTER it did the root.  How silly do I feel!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchOption.AllDirectories` means your code will drill down into (forbidden) territory.

Better be prepared to handle this kind of error. For a solution without catching exceptions you'll need `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` to get FileInfo objects instead of strings and verify your access rights ahead of time.

But you will still need to handle exceptions (File/Dir not found) because of concurrency so you might as well forget about the `FileInfo`s.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the cause of the error message called "Access denied" is ... that you don't have access to that folder!

Try clicking on it in Windows Explorer. You will notice that, in fact, you can't access it. What a surprise ;-) The message told you exactly that.

SearchOption.AllDirectories means that GetFiles will recursively enumerate all files. If it hits an error *somewhere* it will throw an exception. There is no way to change that.

You cannot make Directory.GetFiles ignore access denied errors. So you have to code your own file-system enumeration code. It will probably be a recursive function with some error-handling code in it.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying `SearchOption.AllDirectories` which according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx) means

> > AllDirectories   Includes the current directory and ***all the subdirectories*** in a search operation. This option includes reparse points like mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.

In other words, your search is recursive and walks down into `Documents and Settings` where you have no read permission.

Comment: Isn't it weird that he can access Program Files and can't Documents and setteings?

Comment: @Peri Read permission on `Program Files` isn't really sensitive (it is supposed to be shared) while read permission on users' private files under `Documents and Settings` is sensitive and forbidden for normal users.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Wrong.  `Documents and Settings` is a legacy directory which exists only to redirect user accounts to `C:\Users\*`.  It has no read access to prevent people from using it in hard-coded paths.

Comment: @SLaks I guess legacy status depends on the OS involved, but you're right, even on XP the directory in itself is not read protected, just the user sub directories.